# Symfony dev env for localhost and custom ips

Tags: symfony

I tried google search - no results.

I want so that dev environment would be by default for localhost and other predefined ips. I tried the following after the first line `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;` in `./web/app.php`:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1') {
    require './app_dev.php';
    exit;
}
```

But it gives an exeption - `Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler`. Any ideas?

**Updates**:
What I want. When the ip is localhost I want so that dev environment would be loaded.

**Updates 2**
Symfony ver - 3.2

Comment: you try to change which file ? i don't understand your post

Comment: @t-n-y updated  the question

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be adding a similar check-slightly modified, so that you can add more IPs- right after the `use` statement:

```
$env = 'prod';
if (in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1'], true)) {
    $env = 'dev';
}
```

***and***, later on, change this:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

to this:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel($env, false);
```

This way app.php will load automatically the 'dev' environment on the  IPs you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden if statement and replace this line

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

by

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1') {
    $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
}else{
    $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
}
```

also you can update your web/.htaccess replace all app.php by app_dev.php in all occurrences in below lines

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
```

Comment: What does it give to me. Using a var for env?  A way to get doctrine em? I do not need it.

Comment: Oops ... it looks like I understood your post in the wrong direction .. could you check again